# Why did Protagonist want Kat tell her location to him at the end of the movie?

Tags: tenet

> Kat: Cannon Place, 3:00. Probably nothing, I'm...

Why did Protagonist want Kat tell her location to him at the end of the movie?

Comment: So he could come and rescue her from her husband's thugs, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He gives instructions to Kat earlier on the movie when they're on the ship travelling back towards the 14th:

> PROTAGONIST
> When it’s over, and you’re raising
> your boy. Carry this –

> The Protagonist hands her a DUMB PHONE.

> PROTAGONIST (CONT'D)
> There may be a time and place you
> feel threatened. Hit talk, state
> your location, hang up.

> KAT
> Who gets the message?

> PROTAGONIST
> Posterity.

Apart from possible retribution from Sator's organisation and benefactors, the Protagonist is concerned that Kat is in danger from Tenet:

> PROTAGONIST
> And now it’s your turn. Assuming
> she makes it out alive, whether or
> not you feel she knows too much...

> PRIYA
> I can’t.

> PROTAGONIST
> If you don’t have the authority,
> talk to whoever’s in charge of
> loose ends. I need your word that
> she and her son will be safe.

It would seem that his concern was justified since at the time Kat makes the call, she is bring watched by Priya who is preparing to have Kat eliminated. The Protagonist arrives at the right time and place, after either hearing Kat's message or having had it relayed to him from the future.